# Controlling Spotify through Processing/Arduino

Tags: arduino, processing, spotify

I am making a tangible controller for Spotify (like the one from Jordi Parra, http://vimeo.com/21387481#at=0) using an Arduino microcontroller.

I have a Processing sketch running which does all the calculations with the data from the Arduino. I want this Processing sketch to be able to control different options in Spotify like: Next, Previous, Play/Pause, Volume Up/Down, Shuffle.

Right now I use an extra Arduino Leonardo which simulates key presses while AutoHotKey listens to those and sends them to Spotify. It does not work very well and I only have limited options.

I would love to get rid of that extra Arduino while getting more control.
I am working on a Windows thing so Apple script won't work (for me).

Is there a possibility to control the Spotify app from Processing? Or is it possible to use the library to create a new Spotify app in Processing?

Many thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer: I work at Spotify*

Right now there is no cross-platform way to control the Spotify application. On Linux, Spotify will respond to dbus commands, which means that a bit of hacking could send play/pause/next/previous. I have heard that it is also possible to control Spotify on Mac OSX via applescript, but I'm not 100% certain about this. A quick google search for "control spotify mac os x applescript" produced some interesting results, though I'm not sure how current or relevant any of them are. As for Windows, I'm not sure if/how one would control the application at all.

Otherwise, your best bet would be [libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/), for which you would need to write a Processing library to communicate with it. Based on a bit of quick research, it seems that Processing libraries are written in Java, which means you'd either need to use a wrapper such as [jlibspotify](http://code.google.com/p/jlibspotify/) or hand-roll your own JNI wrapper for libspotify.

I'm not sure how current jlibspotify is, given that they are wrapping a rather old version of the library. If you do any libspotify hacking it is better done in C/C++ with a minimal JNI wrapper, but all of this may be way more work than you are intending for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Why not utilize Spotify's keyboard integration.

The Arduino Leonardo supports USB HID mode.
So, send the keyboard keys for Next, Previous, Play/Pause, Volume Up/Down, Shuffle.

Most everything has a single bound global key. I believe only shuffle does not. You could create a global hotkey in your OS to bind to the app's shuffle control key.

If you are looking for status feedback on the state of each button, this of course won't help you.

Good luck.